# Derivative of integral in one direction

Tags: calculus, integration, leibniz-integral-rule

Suppose I have a 3D scalar field $\phi(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z$ are cartesian coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I can define another 3D field, which is the integral of the field with respect to one dimension

$$ \Phi(x,y,z) = \int_{z}^{\eta} \phi(x,y,z^\prime) \,d z^\prime$$

This has the interpretation of integrating from a depth $z$ to a surface $\eta$, where $\eta(x,y)$ is known and fixed for every $x$ and $y$. If $\phi$ has the interpretation of a density*gravity, this is something like the weight of a material above a point in space.  I am interested in 3 questions:

1. What is the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \Phi = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \int_{z}^{\eta} \phi(x,y,z^\prime) \,d z^\prime$ ?
2. What is the total derivative $\frac{d}{dz} \Phi = \frac{d}{dz} \int_{z}^{\eta} \phi(x,y,z^\prime) \,d z^\prime$ ? Is it the same as the partial derivative in this case?
3. How could I write the line integral $\Phi(z)$ (from a depth $z$ upwards, that is from $(x_0,y_0,z)\to(x_0,y_0,\eta)$) as a volume integral over all 3 spatial coordinates? Something like $\Phi(z) = \int_{z}^{\eta}\int_{A} \phi(x,y,z^\prime) D(x,y,z)\,dA \,dz^\prime$ where $D(x,y,z)$ is something like a delta function. I ask because I need to approximate the integral over predefined 3D blocks where I know 3D quadrature rules.

Any insight for any of the 3 questions would be appreciated!

edit: changed the order of the questions to ask partial derivative first

Comment: Your first two questions should logically be asked in the other order, because the total derivative will be the partial derivative plus extra information. In this case, total derivative implies the other variables are a function of $z$. Is this true and if so, what is that relationship?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I will edit the question. $x,y$, and $z$ are all spatial coordinates, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the "other variables being a function of z"

Comment: $x=x(z)$, etc ?

Comment: Oh I see. No, $x, y, z$ are spatial coordinates so they have no dependence on one another.

Comment: Well, they might be, given that you're doing a line integral. Or maybe the total derivative is meant to be the material derivative, the information here is too sparse to tell.

Comment: Also good points. There is no dependence in the line integral, because I'm always integrating "straight up", that is, I'm interested in the path $(x_0,y_0,z)$ parametrized by depth. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

1)) If for fixed $x$ and $y$, $f(z)=\phi(x,y,z)$ is a continuous function of $z$ then for any primitive $F(z)$ of $f(z)$ we have $$\Phi(x,y,z)=\int_{z}^{\eta} \phi(x,y,z^\prime) \,d z^\prime=F(\eta)-F(z)$$ by Newton-Leibnitz' formula. Then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \Phi(x,y,z)=(F(\eta)-F(z))’=-f(z)=-\phi(x,y,z).$$